# Density in $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$ and let $Y\subset A$ with $x\in Y$ iff $x\in [0,1]$.

I'm trying to prove that $A$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and already noticed that it is enough to show that $Y$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Could any one point me in a direction?

I have already looked at a proof of the density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, where the core of the proof consisted of showing that between any two reals there is a rational. This was done by multiplying the reals with a natural number until the difference between them became bigger than one and noticing that you can find a rational between the two multiplied reals and divide that by the amount the reals got multiplied with and you get a rational between the two reals.

This method does not work identically in this case, because dividing an element in $A$ by a natural number won't always yield another element in $A$.

I will use this, when I have a proof, to prove that the quotient $\mathbb R/{\sim}$ with $r\sim s$ if $r-s=a+b\sqrt{2},\;\exists a,b \in \mathbb Z$ is not hausdorff. The density of every eq. clas in this quotient implies that the quotient topology must be the trivial one, hence the quotient cannot be hausdorff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $0\lt \sqrt{2}-1\lt 1$, and that any integer power of $\sqrt{2}-1$ is of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Given any $\epsilon\gt 0$, we can find an integer $q$ such that $0\lt (\sqrt{2}-1)^q\lt \epsilon$. Now consider the numbers $n(\sqrt{2}-1)^q$, as $n$ ranges over the integers, positive, negative, and $0$. It is not hard to show that for any real number $x$, there is an integer $n$ such that the distance from $n(\sqrt{2}-1)^q$ to $x$ is $\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just the little direction I needed.

Comment: You are welcome. One can prove a stronger result. Let $\gamma$ be **any** irrational number. Then the set of numbers of the form $a+b\gamma$, where $a$ and $b$ range over the integers, is dense in the reals.

Comment: But of course, that is the beauty in your response, you don't use $\sqrt{2}$ explicitly, therefore it can be replaced by any irrational

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use [this application of the pigeonhole principle](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189402/12042) to show that the numbers $b\sqrt2-\lfloor b\sqrt2\rfloor$ for $b\in\Bbb Z$ are dense in $[0,1]$: clearly $\{b\sqrt2-\lfloor b\sqrt2\rfloor:b\in\Bbb Z\}\subseteq A$. The same argument works with any irrational in place of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Looking 'mod 1' is how I intuitively convinced myself that the set is indeed dense, but did not know how to make it explicit, thanks! Too bad I cannot accept 2 answers and upvote both.

Comment: @Sadar: Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate $\sqrt{2}$ as closely as you want with rational numbers $-a/b$.  If $\dfrac{-a}{b}$ is close to $\sqrt{2}$, then $a+b\sqrt{2}$ is close to $0$.  If you can make $a+b\sqrt{2}$ as close as you want to $0$ be suitable choice of $a,b\in\mathbb Z$, then there is no neighborhood of $0$ that excludes all nonzero numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$.  If the set in question were discrete, then it would have only finitely many members in every bounded interval.

Comment: You are going directly to the hausdorffness? Then you should not forget that 0 is in the same eq. class as $a+b\sqrt{2}$ for any $a,b\in\mathbb Z$. How can this be rephrased for any real in $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Sadar: I think the point is more along the lines that if you can make arbitrarily small numbers, then you can use them to get arbitrarily close to any number.