# show that $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\tan{k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cot{k}\right)\le n^3\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}$

Tags: inequality

let $x_{k}>0(k=1,2,3,\cdots,n)$ show that
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\tan{k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}\cot{k}\right)\le n^3\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}$$

My try use  AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$LHS\le \dfrac{(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\tan{k}+\cot{k})x_{k})^2}{4}\le\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\tan{k}+\cot{k})^2}{4}=\dfrac{2n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\cot^2{k}+\tan^2{k})}{4}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^2_{k}$$

Comment: CS is enough, applied to the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose $k$-th components are $\sqrt{x_k|\tan k|}$ and $\sqrt{x_k|\cot k|}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio With your method I get $$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x_k\right)^2\le\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x_k |\tan(k)|\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x_k |\cot(k)|\right)$$ which is not exactly what we want  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please check: $n=12$, $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots = x_{10} \to 0$ and $x_{11} = x_{12} = 1$.

Comment: @RiverLi,maybe the $n^2$ take place of $n^3$ is right?

Comment: @inequality One might be able to use bounds of the form $tan(k)<Ck$ and $cot(k)<Ck$ for some$C$ to complete your proof. See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.08817.pdf The constant $C$ might be chosen arbitrarily close to 1 as $k$ grows I think.

Comment: For those interested, I have tried the following. For a given $n$, let the max of $\tan(k)$ and the max of $\cot(k)$ for $k$ on the interval $[1, n]$ be $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then of course the left sum is less than $$ab\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k\right)^2$$ which is always less than or equal to $$n ab\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2$$ and thus if $ab\leq n^2$ the proof of complete. Unfortunately, as early as $n=22$ for $\tan(14)$ and $\cot(22)$ this fails. Hopefully this saves someone some time.

Comment: @Marco: "See for example"?! The claims in that paper should be treated with skepticism.

Comment: @Dap: Any result should be treated with skepticism unless it is verified by oneself. The bounds for $1/|\sin k|$ in the paper do check out and they are relevant to this problem. Any solution of this problem will have to do with bounding $\tan k$ and $\cot k$.

Comment: It is likely that there is no known answer to this problem. Although $\tan(n)$ is unbounded (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056119/), that doesn't mean  that we know anything about how close we come to some $(k+1/2)\pi$ with growing $n$. The bound constant will depend on the irrationality measure of π, which is unknown. See discussions in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977461/