# Show $\tan(n) < n^q$, conjectured $q < 1.1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, trigonometry

Show $\tan(n) < n^q$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n > 1$. The argument of the $\tan$-function is in radians. It is conjectured that $q < 1.1$.

In fact, search for the maximum of $q$ in $n\in [2, 10^9]$ gives $\tan(260515)= 383610.707744 = 260515^{1.031031}$ and then the next higher $q$'s only at $\tan(122925461)= 326900723.479835 = 122925461^{1.052508}$, and further  $\tan(534483448)= 1914547468.536829 =  534483448^{1.063489}$.

It is known that $\tan(n)$ is unbounded (see [math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056119](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056119)). So it is clear that with increasing $n$,  ever larger $\tan(n)$ will eventually be found. While we know that  $n\ne(k+1/2)\pi$,  that doesn't mean that we know how close $n$ comes to some $(k+1/2)\pi$ with growing $n$.

In the range of $n$ above, it appears that no higher values of $q$ are found, and the conjecture is that such high $n$ are required for higher values of $\tan(n)$, that no higher $q$ will be attained. Possibly the limit for $q$ will have to be made more loose than $q < 1.1$, where derivations of such looser bounds would certainly be appreciated.

For possible relations to the irrationality measure of $\pi$, which is unknown, see discussions in here: [math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977461](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2977461) .

Comment: Make sure to clarify it's particularly in radians! ;)

Comment: @MrPie that's the assumption in higher math

Comment: @MrPie done - thanks.

Comment: Is $n$ restricted to $\mathbb{N}$?  My initial reaction was "obviously not" until I guessed that you might be assuming that.

Comment: @badjohn It says $n \in \cal{N}$ in the first line. Bad character , should be $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Sorry, somehow that did not catch my eye.  I'll blame the combination of my old eyes and using a small tablet.

Comment: PARI/GP code: `for(n=2,+oo,m=log(tan(n))/log(n);if(type(m)=="t_REAL"&&m>1,print1([n,m]," ")))`

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thanks - did you let this code run? What about the infinity limit? PS: I did about the same in MATLAB, however searching for larger m's as it ran.

Comment: I'm running it at the moment, so far I have `[n, q] = [260515, 1.03103086729602]` and `[37362253, 1.00059950756045]`; the first one agreeing with yours. I set it to infinity so that it runs indefinitely (as long as my laptop doesn't crash).

Comment: It may also be interesting to investigate how close $q$ can get to $1$, but that's a different question.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Keep your laptop well lubricated -  let the audience know if higher $q$'s pop up. From Esteban Crespi's answer (below) there is already  $q = 1.087606$ for $n=214112296674652 $ so that's a bit closer to infinity ...

Comment: I've tried finding a counterexample using an extrapolation approach: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53141460#53141460 but it doesn't seem to work as $\tan n-n^{1.1}$ is too sensitive for large $n$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire In  Esteban Crespi's answer (below), a bound of $2.1$ for $q$ is suggested. This is far from 1.1, so you might want to extrapolate with some $q$ in between.

Comment: Would the maxima change much if you used absolute values, and asked about $|\tan(n)|\lt n^q$?

Comment: @BarryCipra If we would do that, there are higher $q$'s for n=11 and n=33. Considering large $n$, for n=573204 we had q=1.134, so there the values are of the same order.

Comment: @Andreas, interesting! Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas, if you look the wikipedia article on Liouville numbers, it is known that $\mu < 1.5$ under the assumption that some series converges. In that case we would have $q \le \mu-1 \le 1.5$  using the same argument that in my answer.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi Thanks. Could you relate that to Marco's answer (below) who gives a more conservative bound? I believe that Marco's answer doesn't make series' convergence assumptions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but I suppose it might be useful (btw I don't know how to answer this question without using the irrationality measure of $\pi$).

Let $\mu$ be a positive real number such that there are infinitely many rational numbers such that 
  $$ \left\vert\pi - \frac{a}{b}\right\vert < \frac{1}{b^\mu} $$
if $\mu$ is the largest such number then we say that $\mu$ is the irrationality measure of $\pi$. It is known (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) that
$$ 2 \le \mu \le 7.60630853 $$

Let as make the assumption that for the true value $\mu$ of $\pi$ we can find infinitely many $a/b$ such that $a$ is even and $b$ is odd and in addition $\pi > a/b$, (this seems very reasonable but I don't have any idea of how it can be proved) then

$$ 0 < \pi - \frac{2n}{2m+1} < \frac{1}{(2m+1)^\mu} $$

and so 
$$ \pi/2 + m\pi - \frac{1}{2(2m+1)^{\mu-1}} < n < \pi/2 + m\pi  $$

observing that $m \approx n/\pi $  we can finally write 
$$  n = \pi/2 + m\pi - \frac{\alpha}{n^{\mu-1}} $$
for some bounded $\alpha >0$.

Now we can use the expression for $n$ in the expansion of $\tan x$ about $\frac \pi2$:
$$ \tan x = -\frac{1}{x-\pi/2} + \frac{1}{3}\left(x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{45}\left(x - \frac \pi2\right)^3 + \cdots$$
and we get:
$$ \tan n = \alpha n^{\mu-1} + O(1) $$

You can see that your conjecture would be true (at least for large enough $n$) if $\mu \le 2.1$ and the assumption above is true.

**remarks:**
If you consider the continued fraction expansion of $\pi$:
$$ \pi = 3 + \frac 1{7 + \frac 1{15+\frac 1{1 + \frac 1{292+\dots}}}} $$
Then the candidates to the fractions $a/b$ above are those obtained from stopping the continued fraction at any point, or the same adding 1 to the last partial quotient. If we keep those fractions that verify the assumption above we get the following candidates for $n$:

```
4                344 0.929204 *
8             260515 1.031030 * 
12           4846147 0.986072 
15         122925461 1.052508 *
17         534483448 1.063489 *
19        3083975227 1.067087 *
22      902209779836 1.026923
26    74357078147863 1.018592 
27   214112296674652 1.087606 *
30 18190586279576483 1.020496
 .....
```

I have looked for the first 10000 convergents and there isn't any one which gives a larger value than tan(214112296674652). As the number increases it seems to approach 1. For example for the convergents found with 1000 partial quotients or more the largest has exponent 1.0033.

Edit: the code I have used to obtain the above data is the following Pari-GP program:

```
\\ change to 100 digits precission
\p 100
A = contfrac(Pi);
M=0;  
h=[A[1],1];
k=[1,   0];
{
    for(r=1,length(A)-2,
        u=h;
        h=u*A[r+1]+k;
        k=u;
        if(h[1]%2==0 && Pi> h[1]/h[2], 
            ex=log(tan(h[1]/2))/log(h[1]/2);
            printf("%3d %20d %.8f %d\n", r+1, h[1]/2, log(tan(h[1]/2))/log(h[1]/2),if(ex>M, M=ex;1,0))
        );
        u = u+h;
        if(A[r+2] != 1 && u[1]%2==0 && Pi> u[1]/u[2],
            ex=log(tan(u[1]/2))/log(u[1]/2);
            printf("%3d %20d %.8f %d\n", r+1, u[1]/2, log(tan(u[1]/2))/log(u[1]/2),if(ex>M, M=ex;1, 0))
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Cool. Are you saying that $q=\mu-1$?

Comment: Very nice approach - thanks!

Comment: (+1) Could you share the code you used to obtain the candidates?

Comment: @lcv. Yes but only if the assumption is true.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I have added the code. It is a very rough Pari-Gp program.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is $\mu$. By definition, for all real $\epsilon,C>0$ and all integers $p,q$ with $q$ large enough:
$$\left | \pi - \frac{p}{q} \right | > \frac{C}{q^{\mu+\epsilon}}.~~~~~(1)$$

Now, let $n$ be any positive integer and write $n=m\pi+c$, where $-\pi/2<c<\pi/2$. If $c<0$, then $\tan n<0<n^q$ for any $q$. Thus, suppose $c>0$. Since $\tan x (\pi/2-x) <1$ for all $x\in (0,\pi/2)$, we have
$$\tan(n)=\tan(c)< \frac{1}{\pi/2-c}\leq \frac{2/(2m+1)}{\pi-2n/(2m+1)}\leq \frac{2}{C}(2m+1)^{\mu+\epsilon-1}\leq \frac{2}{C}(2/\pi)^{\mu+\epsilon-1}n^{\mu+\epsilon-1}.$$
If we let $C=2(2/\pi)^{\mu+\epsilon-1}$, we have shown that: for every $\epsilon>0$, the inequality
$$\tan n <n^{\mu+\epsilon-1},$$
holds for $n$ large enough.

It is currently known that $\mu < 7.11$. So we have the following:

*Theorem. For $n$ large enough: $\tan n<n^{6.11}$.*