# Mantissa of $\pi$ and pigeonhole

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

*It might be worth noting that this is a "pigeonhole principle" problem, but I'm not sure how to use PHP with it.*

**The mantissa of $\pi$ is the fractional part of it (i.e. everything after the decimal place). A question from class asks me to prove that there is a number within the infinite set $\{1\pi, 2\pi, 3\pi, 4\pi, ...\}$ such that taking its mantissa will give me a number less than $0.001$.**

Using a computer, I can actually find out that $10^{600}\pi$ gives me a satisfactory result. That's... kind of cheating though. Approaching the problem in a more mathematical way, I've been looking for patterns in $\pi$ and trying to figure out if I could prove that as I increase to $n\pi$ where $n$ is some large number, the mantissa will be getting lower and lower.

So far, I have noticed that the first two digits of the mantissa of $8\pi$ are "$13$" while for $1\pi$, they are "$14$". This trend continues until $106\pi$, which gives me $0.008$. Aside from that, I haven't made much progress and am still iffy on how this relates to PHP.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Has nothing much to do with $\pi$, it is true for every positive irrational. The proof is by  Pigeonhole argument.

Comment: The proof is by a  Pigeonhole argument. Has been done a number of times on MSE. Maybe Google Stack Exchange, irrational, Pigeonhole Principle, dense.

Comment: You'll find the argument in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/189402/12042).

Comment: How are you showing that with a computer that the fractional part of $10^{600}\pi$ is small? Seems like, unless you have a lot of digits of $\pi$, a computer program is going to be useless here.

Comment: FWIW, there are _much_ smaller values than $m=10^{600}: frac(m\pi) < 0.001$. In fact there are 99 such m under $10^5$, the smallest being 29486: $29486\pi \approx 92633.0009837$