# Tricky proof involving limit points

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, irrational-numbers

Show that for each irrational number $x$ the set of limit points of the sequence

$(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=nx-[nx]$

is the interval $[0,1]$.

($[x]$ is the largest integer $\leq x$)

Any ideas how to prove that?

Comment: There is another proof, using the pigeonhole principle, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/189402/12042).