# Density of a sequence in the unit interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let $\sqrt{a}$ be an irrational number for somepositive real number $a$.
How can someone prove that the sequence $a_n$$=$$\{$$n$ $\sqrt{a}$$\}$ is dense in the 
interval $[0,1]$?
Can someone help me out with a hint?
Thank you in advance!

> we denote by $\{a\}$$=a-[a]$

Comment: I would guess the square-root was a distraction, and this is true for all irrationals

Comment: For example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/multiples-of-an-irrational-number-forming-a-dense-subset

Comment: Yes indeed,you are right. thank you!

Comment: A proof that I find simpler than the one in the duplicate can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/189402/12042).