# Divergence of a sequence with floors and square roots $a_n = n\sqrt2 - [n\sqrt2] + n\sqrt3 -[n\sqrt3]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there any specific approach to prove the divergence of a sequence? For example, I have this problem:

"Prove that the sequence $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$, where $a_n = n\sqrt2 - [n\sqrt2] 
 + n\sqrt3 -[n\sqrt3]$ is divergent"

(the [ ] stands for the floor function )

I tried to solve it by finding to subsequences that have different limits, but it does not seem to work this way.

Comment: Do you know that $\{ n \sqrt{2} \pmod{1} \}$ is dense in $[0,1]$?

Comment: I did not know that. But still I cannot solve the problem (using your fact), neither prove what you said.

Comment: You should try to prove that, for any constant $c\in(0,1)$, there exist an infinite number of values of $n$ such that $n\sqrt2-\lfloor{n\sqrt2}\rfloor>c$ or equivalently $\{n\sqrt2 (\bmod 1)\}$ is dense in $[0, 1]$. Since you have a sum consisting of an infinite number of terms greater than some constant, the sum diverges.

Comment: I tried but I still cannot prove it this way. If you find a solution, will you please post it?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/189402/12042

Comment: @AlgorithmsX: the question is about the sequence, not the series.

Comment: Hint: It is known that $\sqrt2$ is irrational, hence has non-repeating decimals. As $\{10^n\sqrt 2\}$ represents the tail of the number, starting at the $n^{th}$ decimal, it cannot tend to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt{2}+ \sqrt{3}$ is irrational, so is $(a_n)$. Consider the first decimal digit of $(a_{10^m})$. If $(a_{10^m})$ would converge, the first decimal digit must eventually become constant, say $d\in\{0,\ldots,9\}$, i.e. for all $m\geq M$ we have first decimal digit of $(a_{10^m})$ equals $d$. But the first decimal digit of $(a_{10^m})$ is the $m$-th decimal digit of $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$, so that would mean that the irrational number is $d$-periodic, contradiction. So $(a_{10^m})$ doesn't converge and so $(a_{n})$ doesn't converge either.

Comment: There is a little flaw in this reasoning: $\{n\sqrt 2\}+\{n\sqrt 3\}\ne\{n\sqrt 2+n\sqrt 3\}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't follow. The only difference is if the number is starting 1. or 0. and that's why I took the first decimal digit