# Density of a set in $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Is the set $S$ defined by
$$S=\{\{n\pi\}:n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
dense in $(0,1)$?

Here $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$

I cannot proceed ahead after recalling the definition of dense sets. I cannot find any way to solve this problem.

Comment: There is a proof in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189397/why-is-this-quotient-space-not-hausdorff/189402#189402); the result is true for all irrationals, not just $\pi$.

Comment: Check [Kronecker's Approximation Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html).