# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, polynomial-rings

Here is the question I want to answer:

Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}.$

I got this hint:

Hint: Find $u \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]^*$ with $u > 1$ and consider $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} u^{-n}.$

**My question is:**

How can we find this $\zeta$? how can I prove that it is a unit? and why we are taking it from the set of units?should this unit be greater than 1 or less than 1?

Comment: This was my answer! https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3889452/774222 You don't need $\zeta$ to be a unit, per se; what's important in the argument is that $|\zeta| < 1$, so that the union $\cup_n \zeta^n \Bbb{Z}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @RiversMcForge that is correct

Comment: It seems like you got angry with using your answer @RiversMcForge do you want me to delete it?

Comment: @RiversMcForge I deleted your answer ..... could you please delete your comment so that the question becomes compatible? thank you

Comment: I don't thinks he's annoyed by it, but anyhow, I thinks his comment is worth staying, since it gives a reference to a good answer/hint.

Comment: @Confusion It didn't bother me at all. I'm glad it got you thinking about this!

Comment: @Darsen ok as you like.

Comment: @RiversMcForge ok that is great!

Comment: This is known as the [Kronecker's Approximation Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a unit $\zeta$, just an element $\zeta$ such that $0 < \zeta < 1$.  You can start with any element $r$ in your ring that is not integral. Then $\zeta =\{r\} = r - [r]$ is in the interval $(0,1)$, and can be used in your nice argument.

$\bf{Added:}$  For example, consider $r=\sqrt{3}$. We have $[r]=1$.  Take $\zeta= \sqrt{3}-1$, in $(0,1)$, but not a unit ( since its norm $(\sqrt{3}-1)(\sqrt{3}+1)=2>1$).

Comment: so we need its norm to be greater than 1? why?

Comment: why $x$ is at most that distance? why dividing by 2 in the second hint in my question?

Comment: @Confusion: units in a quadratic ring have norm $\pm 1$. Therefore  $\sqrt{3}-1$ is not a unit.

Comment: Why is this a quadratic ring?

Comment: can you please answer my above 2 comments?

Comment: What do you mean by integral? des it means integer?

Comment: Quadratic ring: something like $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$. If you take the integer multiples of some real number $t$, they form a sequence of dots on the real line. Every number $x$ will be between two such dots. The distance between consecutive dots is $t$. So this number $x$ will closer to one of these dots, so closer than $\frac{t}{2}$. Yeah, integral meant there integer.